# How to select parent item and child with highest count using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So this is my database and this is my code for now

```
select distinct continentname, countryname, max(numberoflanguages)
from continent
inner join country on continent.continent = country.continent
group by continentname, countryname
order by continentname
```

It still shows every single continent but I need the top 1 country in every single continent who have the most numberoflanguages.

Kind of like this as output

Please correct me.

Comment: While most answers will have similar syntax, would be good to explain which database you are using.

Comment: Microsoft sql server managment

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: FYI Management Studio is not a database - its a client UI. Your database is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select cc.*
from (select c.continentname, co.countryname, co.numberoflanguages,
             row_number() over (partition by c.continentname order by co.numberoflanguages desc) as seqnum
      from continent c join
           country co
           on c.continent = co.continent
     ) cc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: when I put co.numberoflanguages in the group by it works, but i dont want a extra column called seqnum in my output

Comment: @Smmit . . . Just select the columns you do want.  No `group by` is needed.  You had that in your query and I forgot to remove it.

Comment: Removed the group by still getting seqnum as a column ):

Comment: @Smmit . . . As I say in the question, list the columns you want.  That has nothing to do with the `group by`.